# Refactor & Reference Similar alternatives in eclipse/aptana/netbeans?

Tags: eclipse, zend-framework, netbeans, ide, aptana

where i can find those functions (image attached) in freeware php editors like netbeans, eclise or aptana or similar ide apps (i use it for php and jquery & css)
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Netbeans 7.0 (my favourite for PHP & Zend Framework)

[image]